# rmarkdown greek letters not rendered in maths mode if followed by numbers

Tags: r, r-markdown, math-mode

I want to produce TGF-β1 in an rmarkdown document.

Usually I would do this: `TGF-$\beta$1` but that produces TGF-$$1 when rendered to word, or
[image]
when rendered to pdf.

The problem seems to be the `1` after `beta`. I don't have this problem if it's followed by a letter, e.g. `TGF-$\beta$a` gives TGF-βa

I can get around this by including the `1` in the maths mode: `TGF-$\beta1$` produces TGF-β1

My problem with this is that, in pdf output, the `1` inside the mathmode has a different appearance to a standard text 1:

```
TGF-$\beta1$

TGF-$\beta$ 1
```

[image]

I appreciate this is pedantic, but is there a way around this?

Comment: One way is to change the Mathfont. eg: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30049/how-to-select-math-font-in-document

Comment: Does TGF-$\beta\text{1}$ or TGF-$\beta\mathrm{1}$ work?

Comment: Thanks @DaveArmstrong, both of those work